# solr multicore post data

Tags: java, xml, solr

I am using solar application in multicore mode, and I am unable to post data(xml),when i am trying to post a data by command line(cmd windows) to solr then i get an error...

-> missing solr core name in path

so please give me detailed answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure that the core name is in the path:

`http://host:8983/solr/CORE/update`

When using the post.jar in a multicore setup, you have to override the default url parameter with a url that contains the CORE name:
`java -Durl=http://... -jar post.jar`

You can type `java -jar post.jar -help` to get the list of parameters that can be overridden.

Comment: ya it is in path, but when i gv it a post command like -> java -jar post.jar abc.xml    it give an error -> missing solr core name in path so plz tell me exact command to post a new file for a specific core

Answer (score 1):

```sh
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/update/csv?commit=true' --data-binary @/tmp/tmp/tmp.txt.0.0 -H "Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

The above command works for me. You have to create the csv file for solr index.